# Use of Tense -Situation :- a 35 yr old man explaining to his son how he is so good at football

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

I have played a lot of football in school.

Or

I played a lot of football in school.

Situation :- a 35 yr old man explaining to his son how he is so good at football.

Well,  football that he had learnt in school, still has its connection with the present (he is still good at it) so I think we should use Present Perfect, but  he left school way before, so I also think we should use simple past. Which one's correct ? Please explain!

Comment: "still has its connection with the present " is one of the worst descriptions of the Present Perfect. All past actions have a connection with the present. But you should ask this over on ELL (English Language Learners).

Comment: Ask yourself ... is the 'playing football **in school**' still ongoing? (Though I wouldn't consider the use of the present perfect totally unacceptable here, though preferably when speaking to a stranger, for the reason you suggest might apply.)

Comment: @clare yeah you're right ,for instance an actor has invited a journalist  to his house and is showing him the trophies that he has  ever won, so what should he say- the front row of trophies are the ones that I won/have won for my first film. Provided that the trophies were won by him at a specific point in the past, but as most books describe any repeative thing in the past with no particular time mentioned should be written in present perfect.